# SATA II or III for external hard drive enclosure?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, sata

I want to put the hard drive (500GB) that came with my MacBook Pro (13" mid 2012) in an external (USB 3.0) hard drive enclosure. Are there any benefits to choosing one with the SATA III (6Gb/s) interface for this hard drive, or would SATA II (3Gb/s) work just as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SATA II enclosure will work just fine. A benefit of getting the SATA III is that it will be compatible with drives you install at a later date. So if the price difference is negligible then go for III.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Andrew! I have a hard time figuring out if the hard drive (Model "APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384") is SATA III compliant at all or not. Do you know?

Comment: HTS547550A9E384 is SATA II (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_-_3_Gbit.2Fs_-_300_MB.2Fs) a google search just for the part number gets you some good infos as to the specs. Glad to help!